# Dealing with invariant nouns in Ember router

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I curious how others deal with naming Ember routes when the singular and plural of the obvious word are the same and you want a route for displaying all of that type along with a dynamic route for the individual items.

To take an example from the docs:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
  this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' });
});
```

Great. Now, what if, instead of posts and a post, you had series. You can no longer use this pattern. What you want is for `/series` to be a collection of all the series, and for `/series/:series_id` to show each individual series. What I've come up with is just using a longer name:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('series', { path: '/series' });
  // not nested so that series route isn't activated
  this.resource('series-instance', { path: '/series/:series_id' });
});
```

Here's a different example, where the issue is not that the word is invariant but that there is no single word for the sigular:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('staff', { path: '/staff' });
  this.resource('staff-member', { path: '/staff/:staff_id' });
});
```

Is there a better way to do this or have I pretty much arrived at the best current solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can specify whatever you like for the path value, independent of grammar.
I think what you describe is a valid approach and i have been using this as well as the following for nested resources.

```
    App.Router.map(function() {
      this.resource('series', { path: '/series' },function(){
        this.resource('series-instance', { path: '/:series_id' });
      });
    });
```

The nested resource will be triggered by visiting something like `/series/4` .